# Dynamically extract data for previous month

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to generate data every month for the previous month.

```
set (startdate, enddate) = ('2021-02-01', '2021-02-28');
```

Instead of manually inserting the date every month as in the above code, I want the 'startdate' variable to automatically pick the start date of previous month and the 'enddate' variable to pick the last date of previous month.

How to do that using sql?

Comment: Please provide data in a tabular format.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the previous month relative to the current date, you can just put it into a `where` clause:

```
where datecol < date_trunc('month', current_date) and
      datecol >= date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 month'
```

Note that this is safer than your code, because it works when the column has a time component.

You could put this into variables.  I'm not sure that is necessary.

If you wanted this as variables, you *could* use:

```
(date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 month',
 last_day(date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 month')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after ?

```
select 
     current_date()                         today 
   , date_trunc(month,add_months(today,-1)) first_day_last_month 
   , last_day ( first_day_last_month)       last_day_last_month
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In instances where your version of SQL doesn't support the `date_trunc()` function, you can use something like this:

```
declare 
    @year varchar(10) = YEAR(GETDATE()),
    @month varchar(10) = MONTH(GETDATE()),
    @day varchar(10) = DAY(getdate()),
    @beginyear varchar(10) = YEAR(GETDATE()),
    @beginmonth varchar(10) = MONTH(GETDATE()),
    @begindate date, 
    @enddate date

if @month = 1
    begin 
        set @beginyear = @year - 1
        set @beginmonth = 12
    end

if @month <> 1
    begin
        set @beginmonth = @month - 1
    end


set @begindate = (select @beginyear + '-' + @beginmonth + '-' + '1')
set @enddate = (select @year + '-' + @month + '-' + '1')

Select [your data] from table where [date] between @begindate and @enddate
```